# Return double from vector multiplication with Armadillo C++

Tags: c++, vector, armadillo, vector-multiplication

Do you know why I cannot store in a double the result from a vector multiplication ?

```
double A = rowvec({1,3,4})*vec({5,6,7});
```

It gives "no suitable conversion function from "const arma::Glue"... to "const double" exists.

Still that matrix vector multiplication gives a double.
How can I get around ?

Thank you!

Comment: Use [as_scalar0](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#as_scalar) to convert a 1x1 matrix to a scalar. For example: `double A = as_scalar( rowvec({1,3,4})*vec({5,6,7}) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the product is an expression template called `arma::Glue` which can be converted to a 1x1 matrix.  To do this inline and assign it to a double evaluate it explicitly using `.eval()` and take the only element which is (0,0).

```
#include <armadillo>

int main() {
  using arma::rowvec;
  using arma::vec;
  double A = (rowvec({1,3,4})*vec({5,6,7})).eval()(0,0);
};
```

*N.B.:* Did you mean [`dot(a,b)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#dot)?

```
#include <armadillo>

int main() {
  using arma::rowvec;
  using arma::vec;
  using arma::dot;
  double A = dot(rowvec({1,3,4}), vec({5,6,7}));
};
```

Comment: It's better to use [as_scalar()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#as_scalar) in this case. Use of [.eval()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) is not really recommended as it can degrade performance.